# Interval (step) for seconds in kendo ui chart

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, intervals, seconds

I am working on Kendo chart. I am trying to load date on the X axis and decimal value on Y.
I have generated 500 points using controller. Here is my controller.

```
        List<jsonmodel> arrret = new List<jsonmodel>();
        DateTime start = new DateTime(2015, 09, 14, 01, 20, 00);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            decimal randomnumber = rnd.Next(10, 40);
            DateTime secondsincreament = new DateTime();
            secondsincreament = start;
            arrret.Add(new jsonmodel()
            {
                close = randomnumber,
                date = secondsincreament.ToString(),
            });
            start = start.AddSeconds(3);
        }

        return Json(arrret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I have started from 14/09/2015 01:20:00 and incremented 3 seconds with each loop for X axis and a random number for Y axis.

Using ajax in Jquery, I have created and array and pushed points to that array.

```
dataSource.push({ "x": new Date(data.date), "y": data.close });
```

And then, the Kendo chart goes as following.

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    title: {
        text: "time stamp chart"
    },
    dataSource: {
        data: dataSource
    },
    series: [{
        type: "scatterLine",
        aggregate: "avg",
        xField: "x",
        yField: "y",
    }],
    xAxis: {
        min: new Date("2015/09/14 01:18:00"),
        max: new Date("2015/09/14 01:46:00"),
        labels: {
            template: "#= kendo.toString(value,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')#",
            baseUnit: "seconds",
        },
        crosshair: {
            visible: true,
            tooltip: {
                template: "#= kendo.toString(value,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')#",
                visible: true,
            },
        },
    },
    yAxis: {
        crosshair: {
            visible: true,
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
            },
        },
    },
    autoBaseUnitSteps: {
        seconds: [3]
    }
});
```

Problem is, Data is loading properly on the chart but not all dates (with seconds generated from the controller) are displayed on X axis.

[image]

I cant figure how to set interval (steps) for seconds on scatterLine chart.
Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks